# How to validate JSON against hyper-schema with json-schema-validator

Tags: java, json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I cannot figure out how to properly setup a hyper-schema to work with json-schema-validator. I am using the java version of json-schema-validator, version is 2.2.5.

My schema is:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draftv4/hyper-schema#",
"title": "User object",
"description": "A user representation",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "email": {
        "description": "The user's email address",
        "format":"email",
        "maxLength": 255
    },
    "picture": {
        "description": "The user's picture",
        "type": "string",
        "media": {
            "binaryEncoding": "base64",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    }
}
}
```

My json object is:

```
{"email":"k@w.de",
"picture":null}
```

Now, when I load up the schema into `JsonSchemaFactory` and intend to start validating I get the following warning:

```
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [media]
level: "warning"
schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/picture"}
domain: "syntax"
ignored: ["media"]
```

Is there anything else to configure for using the hyper-schema besides the $schema field?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your $schema is wrong!

It should be `http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema#`. See [section 6 of the core specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor22) for the list of well-known URIs.

Comment: OK. This worked. I can now address the hyper schema. However, if I provide an invalid base64 String, e.g. "Abc der..." as picture value then no errors are reported whatsoever. Moreover, the "readOnly" attribute is also not recognised and leads to the same warning as stated above.

Comment: There are two separate issues here: base64 and readOnly. Would you mind [opening an issue](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/issues) with the two problems? In the issue please paste the full schema and data you are trying to validate.